# Is there a way to change the orientation of a cloned collection of blocks?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I know how to use the `clone` command to copy a collection of blocks between specified coordinates for a `lower-near-right` and `upper-far-left` of the area to be copied, to the `lower-far-left` of the area to copy to:

```
clone    0 4 0    -5 9 -5      5 4 5
      |  from  |     to    | destination
```

The command above will copy a `5x5x5` collection of blocks to the coordinate `5, 4, 5` where that coordinate is the *lower-far-left* corner of the copied blocks, filling away from the world origin, towards the `lower-near-right` corner specified as the clone area starting point:

[image: Screenshot demonstrating the from and destination points of a clone command execution.]
<sub>*The gold blocks are the `lower-near-right` corner of the cloned area and the diamond blocks are the `lower-far-left` corner.*</sub>

With that in mind, I often find myself wanting to copy a collection of blocks to a new area with a new orientation. For example, let's say I wanted to create a cross where each arm is a `2x1x3` collection of any block type. I want to be able to create the first arm, then clone it, rotated 90 degrees, then repeat the rotate and clone until I have all four arms leaving me to simply fill in the center:

[image: Screenshot denoting a proper clone with rotation as desired.]

---

Is there a way to either:

- Clone with a *lower-right* and *upper-left* position specified for the destination?
- Clone with a specified rotation on say the y-axis?

**NOTE**: Creating a custom behavior pack isn't out of the question, so long as I can easily execute the clone.

<sub>*The definitions of `lower-far-left`, `lower-near-right`, and `upper-far-left`, in the context of this post, are, with respect to the origin of the world located at `0, 0, 0` where: `lower-far-left` denotes a smaller value all three axes, `lower-near-right` denotes a smaller value on the y-axis with a larger value on the x and z axes, and `upper-far-left` denotes a larger value on the y-axis with a smaller value on the x and z axes.*</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Did you happen to try the [Structure Block](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Structure_Block) yet? Just note that rotation of custom blocks are not yet possible.

**Unrelated Tip:** For the source coordinates, it does not matter which corner you specify first in the `/clone` command, but the destination corner will always be the one which is towards negative infinity on all of X, Y, and Z.